# Jacoco custom package specification for recording the coverage

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

**Question:** How can I configure jacoco maven plugin to show the coverage report relative to a custom package ? (and not the default one : package of the class that it is executing).

**Project structure :**

```
testprj
  |
  + -- pom.xml     // parent pom
  |
  + -- starter     // Aggregates (as dependencies) all other modules
  |       +        
  |       |
  |       + /src/main/java/com/my/prj/testprj/starter/MainApplication.java  // Springboot starter cls
  |       |
  |       + /src/test/java/com/my/prj/testprj/starter/ProjectIT.java        // Integration tests
  |       |
  |       + -- pom.xml
  |
  + -- core        // acts as a controller
  |       +
  |       |
  |       + ...
  |       |
  |       + -- pom.xml
  |
  + -- dbmock      
  |       +
  |       |
  |       + ...
  |       |
  |       + -- pom.xml
  |
  + -- gateway     // REST endpoint
  |       +
  |       |
  |       + ...
  |       |
  |       + -- pom.xml
  |   
  + target/coverage/jacoco-it/jacoco-it.exec
                       |
                       + ... 
                       |
                       + index.html     // Jacoco Coverage Report
```

**Jacoco configuration :**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
               <destFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/coverage/jacoco-it/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/coverage/jacoco-it/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/coverage/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Failsafe configuration :**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>    
        <argLine>${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Remarks :**

1) I tried to get past the aggregation functionality which is not supported by jacoco maven plugin in a multi-module environment, by running all the tests from a central module that aggregates all others in the classpath and by using the same package prefix in all of them **com/my/prj/testprj/**

2) **Issue :** Coverage reports are displayed for **com/my/prj/testprj/starter** package (the package that contains the test class). I want to display the coverage relative to **com/my/prj/testprj/**

3) IntelliJIdea IDE easily supports this (using Jacoco) by letting me specify the package for which to record coverage data, pls see below :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the [`report-aggregate`](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) goal? As I read the docs, report-integration generates a report for integration tests, it doesn't say anything about aggregating across modules. The `report-aggregate` goal says it does this aggregation.

Comment: It doesn't help, it simply aggregates the reports from each sub-module after trying to run the integration tests defined in each of them. As I have the integration tests defined only in the global module (starter), all the others modules will appear with zero coverage (since they don't actually have integration tests defined in them).